# How do I show names (aliases) for conda environments from different Anaconda versions?

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am trying to show names (aliases) for conda environments from both Miniconda as well as Aanaconda. Currently, my default conda executable comes from Miniconda.

For some background, I have Miniconda installed in `$HOME/packages/miniconda3` and Anaconda installed in `/opt/anaconda3/` (perhaps there is a better way of doing this, but this is just how the installation ended up happening for projects I'm working on).

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  $HOME/packages/miniconda3
ai                       $HOME/packages/miniconda3/envs/ai
test-project             $HOME/packages/miniconda3/envs/test-project
                         /opt/anaconda3
                         /opt/anaconda3/envs/interviews
                         /opt/anaconda3/envs/teaching
```

I have slightly edited the output here like abbreviating my home directory as $HOME and renaming some of the conda environments.

Currently my `base` environment for Miniconda is in `$HOME/packages/miniconda3` and my `base` environment for Anaconda is in `/opt/anaconda3`. I would like my three Anaconda environments to also show their alias names (like the Miniconda environments do) so that I can activate between a Miniconda and Anaconda environment without having to copy the full path, such as `conda activate /opt/anaconda3/envs/interviews`.

Is there a way to enable this name aliasing for both Miniconda and Anaconda simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should not be installing Miniconda and Anaconda side-by-side. If you need an Anaconda environment, just use Miniconda and create an env with the `anaconda` metapackage.

Despite my concern there, the nameability of environments is controlled by whether the subsuming folder is listed in the `envs_dirs` configuration setting. Hence, you should be able to get the behavior you want with something like

```
conda config --append envs_dirs /opt/anaconda3/envs
```