# Use a conda environment activation alias

Tags: python, conda, mini-forge

To activate my Conda environment I have got to type `conda activate /Users/ioannis/miniforge3/envs/env_tf` but I would like to only have to type `conda activate env_tf`. I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474034/how-do-i-show-names-aliases-for-conda-environments-from-different-anaconda-ver) but it has not worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Which OS are you using?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "has not worked"? What happened and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: I'm using macOS.

Comment: @Robert: I typed  `conda config --append envs_dirs /opt/anaconda3/envs`  but got the error `Warning: '/opt/anaconda3/envs' already in 'envs_dirs' list, moving to the bottom`. What  I expected to happen is that when I would then type `conda info --envs` (solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474034/how-do-i-show-names-aliases-for-conda-environments-from-different-anaconda-ver) I would get, as an output `env_tf  /Users/ioannis/miniforge3/envs/env_tf`, but instead I get `                      *  /Users/ioannis/miniforge3/envs/env_tf`.

Comment: may be you could run source activate your_condenv_name I guess.

Comment: "*I typed [...] `/opt/anaconda3/envs`*" - but the environment you want is under `/Users/ioannis/miniforge3/envs`. Add that.